# Distribute same WebI Report to different audiences with different filters

Tags: business-objects, webi

I just started using SAP Web Intelligence and I have a couple of reports ready to deploy for end users. The report includes a "Region" field, and I want each user to be able to only see data in their respective "Region".

I know I can make several copies of the report and filter by each region, but this will make it difficult to maintain.

Does anyone know how I can use the same Report but set different filters for the end-users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **row-level** security.  This is done in the universe, and will cause a condition to be inserted into the report's SQL to restrict results based on the user's credentials.

The "out-of-the-box" method for implementing row-level security is accessed in UDT via Tools -> Manage Security -> Manage Access Restrictions, or in IDT via Window -> Security Editor.  The interfaces are very different, but accomplish the same result -- you select a group and create a condition that should be applied for all members in that group.

You can also implement row-level security without using the built-in security managers described above.  If you have a table in your database that contains a mapping of user ID to region, the logic can be implemented right in the universe.

Note that in both of the above solutions, the security is implemented by adjusting the report's SQL.  If the users have the ability to modify SQL, then they can override the security.  This may or may not be a concern for you, but it is worth being aware of.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Is the report being published as pdf or xls/xlsx?

If so, you can create a (one) generic report and use [Region] as a prompted query filter.

When scheduling the report you can set the prompt to match your audience, and publish directly to them via mailing list also set up scheduling the report.

You will need one schedule per region/audience.

This keeps maintenance at a reasonable level as there's only one report to maintain.

//C